# Rails Base Controller for admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, admin, radix

Im migrating from .net to rails and im a beginner. I have played around but cant figure out how can i create a base controller for admin namespace to share some functionality. I mean, where to put the Base class because i get errors for each try.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assume that you are using Rails 3.
You can do like this.

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

Here is the structure of controllers folder:

```
controllers/
  application_controller.rb
  admin/
    base_admin_controller.rb
    users_controller.rb
```

**admin/base_admin_controller.rb:**

```
class Admin::BaseAdminController < ApplicationController
  protected

    def some_shared_method
      # Do something
    end
end
```

You can add any methods that all admin controllers will share. Then just simply inherit the BaseAdminController class.

**admin/users_controller.rb:**

```
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::BaseAdminController
  def index
    some_shared_method
  end
end
```